# Sliding images with css endlessly

Tags: css

I would like to achieve an image slider that rotates infinitely but only use css.  I was hoping I can maybe achieve that with webkits.

Here is an example of what I want the end result to look like: http://www.team-dignitas.net/

Look at the sponsors, the images are going to the left and its an endless loop.  They've done with carousel jquery but I want to get that achieved with css.  Is it possible?  Does anyone has a guide I can look at to accomplish this?

What I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/3k4cJ/

```
html
```

Comment: the "infinite" effect is accomplished by moving one of the elements from the beginning position to the end at each step. I don't think this can be done purely with CSS.

Comment: You're going to want to set up an infinite css animation. Here is a good article on css-tricks about just that. [http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

Comment: show us your html and what you tried so far :)

Answer (score 3):

You need https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel is exactly the one used in this web (https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgrif1ougt48z87/Screenshot%202014-01-27%2001.41.29.png). This demo's web it's down right now, but you can download the source code from Github and try it in your computer.

But if you want pure css would be better for you learn the basics concepts of CSS3 animations. This post is really good for that http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/ and use the same example "CSS3 Cycle Image Slider"

Option 2: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/#

Option 3: http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl

Option 4: http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/

Comment: what do you mean by needs some controls before?

Comment: I mean that must create the controls like "next" and "prev" in this example.

Comment: is there a way to make it pause for 2-3 seconds and then move on to the next one?

Comment: Yeah of course. See this code http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl and check "autoplay". You only need setup the JS timer.

Comment: Other nice option is http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/ with autplay and timer with pure CSS

Comment: see, i think i haven't explained exactly what I want.  I don't want to see a single image, I want a line of images just like it is on team-dignitas website.  The option 1 you have given me does exactly that, however how would I modify that in order to see it behave with stop and go?  Additionally, is it possible to add previous and next button (this part does not need to css) and can I add a clickable link on each image, depending on which image you click on.

Comment: Ohh man, ok so you need https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel is exactly the one used in this web (https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgrif1ougt48z87/Screenshot%202014-01-27%2001.41.29.png). This demo's web it's down right now, but you can download the source code from Github and try it in your computer.

Comment: i don't want jquery, I need the slider to keep running even if i disable javascript on my browser.  The 2 buttons can be broken at that point but I need the slider to keep working :)

Comment: Oh ok. I know how but I'll see this case tomorrow, I need sleep now. I'm very tired right now ^^

Comment: So you need learn the basics concepts of CSS3 animations. This post is really good for that http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/ and use the same example "CSS3 Cycle Image Slider"